# MySQL group concat conversion to Postgres using two concatenated columns

Tags: mysql, postgresql, concatenation, group-concat

How can I create a similar query using Postgres to recreate this MySQL version.

```
SELECT u.id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(r.firstname,' ',r.lastname, ' [', r.type,']') SEPARATOR ', ') AS names
FROM reference r, users u
WHERE r.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY r.user_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`string_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE). Also, use explicit join syntax.

```
SELECT u.id, string_agg(r.firstname || ' ' || r.lastname || ' [' || r.type || ']' , ', ') AS names
FROM reference r join users u
on r.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY r.user_id
```

Comment: This worked perfect, thanks! Been struggling with this for a bit so much appreciated.